# suppressing printing every assignment

Tags: octave

I have written a simple script in Octave. When I run it from the command line, Octave prints a line every time a variable gets assigned a new value. How do I suppress that?

MWE:

```
function result = stuff()
    result = 0
    for i=0:10,
        j += i
    end
end
```

when I run it:

```
octave:17> stuff()
result = 0
result = 0
result =  1
result =  3
result =  6
result =  10
result =  15
result =  21
result =  28
result =  36
result =  45
result =  55
ans =  55
octave:18>
```

I want to get rid of the `result = ...` lines.
I am new to Octave, so please forgive me asking such a basic question.

Comment: As mentioned, ending your lines with a `;` will suppress the output to the terminal. Also you don't need the `,` after the `for` line. Lastly, although `j += i;` is valid Octave, it is not valid Matlab. I would suggest you change it to `j = j + i` so that if your code ever needs to be ported to Matlab, you won't have to make any changes.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

by adding a semicolon at the end of your statement it will suppress the intermediate result.

In your case:

```
function result = stuff()
    result = 0;
    for i=0:10,
        j += i;
    end
end
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 18):

Like in matlab just add a ; (semicolon) to the end of a line you don't want output to the terminal.